# How to validate an email in middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to validate an email on a middleware, so what I need is if the user's email isn't an email then it needs to redirect to a specific page, but I'm not sure how to validate that. I know with a form you use `$request->validate([])`, but I'm not sure on how do it in my case.

Here is my middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $validate = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'email'
    ]);

    if(!$validate)
    {
        return redirect('/wrong-email');
    }
}
```

Comment: why you want to put in `middleware` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's better to do it directly in your controller. But if you insist on doing it on a middleware, you can directly use the `Validator` facade:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

...

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'email' => 'email',
  ]);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('/wrong-email');
  }

  return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can manually create a validator:

```
 $validator = Validator::make([
        'email' =>$request->input(email)
    ], [
            'email' => 'email',
        ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/wrong-email');
        }
```

or just use your $request:

```
$request->validate([
        'email' => 'email'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
    ]);

if ($v->fails())
{
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
}

//
```